# SharePoint disabled images after copy pages to other sites

Tags: image, sharepoint, migration

I use PowerAutomate flow to migrate pages from one site to another.
Problem is my pictures from new site from migrated pages keep linked to original pictures, and if someone dosen't have accsess from first site he can't see pictures on the second site.

Please help to solve issue.

(Original site contain pictures, copy of site contain pages from the first site that copied links for pictures from first site. If user don't have acsess to first site he can't see images on second site)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following methods:

1. Give the user in the second site the permissions in the first site.
2. Copy the picture from the first site to the second site, and then modify the link pointing to the picture in the page to redirect to the picture in the second site.